# SystemVerilog memory with 32'hFFFFFFFF top address fails

Tags: system-verilog

The following memory declaration returns 0when I run this simulation:

```
module test;

    bit [31:0] mem[32'hFFFFFFFF:0] ;

    initial begin
        mem[32'hdeadbeef] = 32'hbaddadda;
        $display("%h", mem[32'hdeadbeef]);
    end 
endmodule // test
```

Results in:

```
# run -all
# 00000000
# quit
```

But if I change the memory declaration so that the high address is `32'hdeadbeef` then the simulation runs normally.

It appears that the high address is assume to be a signed integer. How does one create a memory for a 32-bit address?

Comment: this array is just too big. check errors and warnings in your compilation.

Comment: This is more of a type problem.  Apparently the high end address is a signed integer.

Answer (score 4):

Your range for an unpacked array is likely too big ([32'hFFFFFFFF:0] is 2<sup>32</sup> entries). Simulators are required to support at least 2<sup>24</sup> entries. A packed array (aka vector) portion are is required to support at least 2<sup>16</sup> bits. Simulators can support larger, but you are likely better off using associative arrays (ex: `bit [31:0] mem [ bit [31:0] ]`). This will give you the desired address range, but try to limit the total number of entries as you can run out of memory.

---

Citations:

[IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 6.9.1 Specifying vectors

> Implementations may set a limit on the maximum length of a vector, but the limit shall be at least 65536 (2<sup>16</sup>) bits.

[IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 7.4.1 Packed arrays

> The maximum size of a packed array can be limited, but shall be at least 65 536 (2<sup>16</sup>) bits.

[IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 7.4.2 Unpacked arrays

> Implementations may limit the maximum size of an array, but they shall allow at least 16 777 216 (2<sup>24</sup>) elements.

Answer (score 1):

The SystemVerilog LRM section **6.9.1 Specifying vectors** says

> Both the msb constant expression and the lsb constant expression shall
>   be constant integer expressions. The msb and lsb constant expressions
>   (see 11.2.1) may be any *integer* value—positive, negative, or zero.

And an *integer* is a 32-bit signed type. Declaring a full 32-bit addressable memory would take 4.2Gb. Imagine how much simulation time you would need to access every element. You are better off declaring it as an associative array.

```
typedef bit [31:0] uint32_t;

uint32_t mem[uint32_t];
```

Comment: I somehow lost my copy of the LRM. This confirmed what I suspected.